# how to only close boto3 debug info in scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, boto3

I use Scrapy with aws boto3, there are a lot of debug info from boto3.
how can I only close boto3 debug info? I still need scrapy debug info. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

use

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('s3transfer').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```