# How to get debug logs from boto3 in a local script?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, logging, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a local script that lists buckets:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:
    print(bucket['Name'])
```

when I execute it locally, it does just that. Now if I execute this code as a lambda on AWS and set the log level to `DEBUG`, like so:

```
import boto3
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url="http://localhost:4566")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_client.list_buckets()
    return { "statusCode": 200 }
```

I get detailed logs such as the headers of the HTTP request that is sent to S3.

But If I add these lies to my local script nothing changes. I've tried:

```
import boto3
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:
    print(bucket['Name'])
```

and

```
import boto3
import logging

logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('s3transfer').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:
    print(bucket['Name'])
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48576861) and in both cases I get no logs.
How can I get my local script the show the logs for what boto3 does under the hood?

Comment: please combine that all into a reproducible example so we can give it a try.  Simply concatenating the disparate lines together would only be a guess at what you did, and a waste of time.

Comment: boto3 installs a logger handler that outputs all records it gets.  To replicate this behavior locally without adding a custom handler, you can call `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` before you call any methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
import boto3
import logging

boto3.set_stream_logger('', logging.DEBUG)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:
    print(bucket['Name'])
```

Spews out a whole bunch of stuff.  [From this doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html#boto3.set_stream_logger)

Answer (score 0):

Adding one log line of my own seems to trigger the botocore logs being printed as well. I have no idea why though.

```
import boto3
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug("hello?")

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:
    print(bucket['Name'])
```